# PHP - how to sort array of arrays by specified value?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have created an array in php, and I would like to sort the indented array of an array by their names, not by alphabetical order.
Code below:

```
$arr = array("ID"=>"001",
             "c"=>array()
);

$products = ['apple','orange','kiwi','banana'];

foreach($products as $product){

    $arr['c'][]=array(
        "product" => $product
    );

}

print_r($arr);
```

above code will print:

```
    Array(

    [ID] => 001[c] => Array(
          [0] => Array(
            [product] => apple
        ) [1] => Array(
            [product] => orange
        ) [2] => Array(
            [product] => kiwi
        ) [3] => Array(
            [product] => banana
        )
    )
)
```

and I want to sort them in the result like below:

```
Array(

    [ID] => 001[c] => Array(
          [0] => Array(
            [product] => orange 
        ) [1] => Array(
            [product] => apple
        ) [2] => Array(
            [product] => banana
        ) [3] => Array(
            [product] => kiwi
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: _and I want to sort them in the result like below:_ That does not look sorted to me

Comment: sorry about my english, it re-order them like orange is the first of array and so on thanks

Comment: Do you mean you want them sorted in decending order?

Comment: "And so on?" I don't see any order in the second example that makes sense.

Comment: not decent or alphabetical order, I want to sort them manually by its values. the product array was a response from API call, and I want to re-order them manually like 'orange', 'apple', 'banana', 'kiwi'.

Comment: But that is not sorted in any order that a sort algorithm would understand, that is a randon order

Comment: maybe the terminology in this case is not called sorting/ordering but I would like the responsed array (['apple','orange','kiwi','banana']) to be print in the order that I want to specify, not sure if its possible

Comment: Did you look at the multisort array php has? That might be what you need. Otherwise an array containing keys that has the order you want sorted via a loop may be required.

Answer (score 0):

An interesting situation that I'd try to avoid.

If you already know what order things should be in, add them in the correct order.

```
$arr = array("ID"=>"001",
             "c"=>array()
);

$products = ['apple','orange','kiwi','banana'];

$myCustomSortValuesInOrder = array (
    'orange', 'apple', 'banana', 'kiwi'
);

foreach($myCustomSortValuesInOrder as $orderVal) {
    $key = array_search($orderVal, $products);
    if($key !== false) {
        $arr['c'][]=array(
            "product" => $products[$key];
        );
    }
}

print_r($arr);
```